# How to reduce memory usage?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to generate pickle file of the predictions on my dataset. But after executing the code for 6 hours PC is going out of memory again and again. I wonder if anyone can help me with this?

```
from keras.models import load_model
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

import pickle
import os
import cv2
import glob

dirlist = []

imgdirs = os.listdir('/chars/')
imgdirs.sort(key=float)
for imgdir in imgdirs:
    imglist = []
    for imgfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('/chars/', imgdir, '*.png')):
        img = cv2.imread(imgfile)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        model = load_model('mymodel.h5')
        predictions=model.predict(img)
        print('predicted model:', predictions)
        imglist.append(predictions)

      dirlist.append(imglist)
q = open("predict.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(dirlist,q)
q.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why you reload your model for every prediction?
Code would be much faster, if you load your model only once and then do the prediction.
Also if you load several pictures at once and you predict in batches that also would be a big speed boost.

What out of memory error do you get?
One from the tensorflow(or which backend you're using) or one from python?
My best guess would be that load_model is loading the same model over and over in the same tensorflow session till your resource is exhausted.
The Solution is, as stated above, to just load the model at the beginning once.

Comment: I am using spyder (Python 3.6) with tensorflow backend. A message is displayed on the screen that PC is out of memory and Spyder just shut down.

Comment: Well still my guess would be you load to many models inside your session. (Every time you call load_model your model with the op and weights is fully loaded without deleting the old version). The other unlikely scenario is that you run out of memory with the dirlist array, which shape does your prediction have and how many pictures do you want to process?

Comment: Sure but why not loading your model once? It is the same model for all prediction, isn't it?

Comment: yeah it's the same model, I'll try your suggestion.